# How do I use jquery to change a previous div background color?

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is, if a div is clicked on, that div and its predecessors have the same background color. For example if '4' is clicked on; 4, 3, 2 and 1 have the same background color.  I tried unsuccessfully to achieve this, how do I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/KPS7a/

```
<style type="text/css">
.selectcontainer {
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
}

.select {
display:block
width:50px;
height:40px;
background-color:#59758d;
text-align:center;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:24px;
cursor:pointer;
padding-top:10px;
}
.select:hover {
border:1px solid #d99c29;

font-size:32px;
}


</style>
<script type"text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.select').live('click',function() {
var i = $(this).attr('id');

$('.select').each(function(i){
    $('.select').css({'background-color':'green'});
});

});

});
</script>
<div class='selectcontainer'>

<div class='select' id='1'>1</div>
<div class='select' id='2'>2</div>
<div class='select' id='3'>3</div>
<div class='select' id='4'>4</div>
<div class='select' id='5'>5</div>
<div class='select' id='6'>6</div>


</div>
```

Comment: also just worth mentioning that an `id` should not start with a numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main error: `id` is an undefined variable. You have to add quotes around it.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KPS7a/3/**

Additional changes to get the code to work:

- Added quotes around `.attr(id)` -> `.attr("id")`
- Renamed `var i` to `var id`
- Changed the inner `$(".select")` to `$(this)`
- Changed `.css("background-color", "green")` to `.addClass("green")`
  Added a new declaration to the CSS: `.green { background-color: green}`
  Added `$(".green").removeClass("green")` at the beginning of the `click` event, **so that the color will reset** on each click (previously, every tile will still be green if you first click at 5, then 1)

Answer (score 1):

Also in your jsfiddle you haven't referenced jQuery.
I've also made a modified version for you which I think is simpler (but requires the html you provided to be unchanged): http://jsfiddle.net/6386x/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Like Rob mentioned you need to change `id` to '`id'` since id is undefined variable.

```
var i = $(this).attr('id');
```

You can also modify your code to something like this:

```
$('.select').live('click',function() {
    $(this).prevAll('div.select').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/7w2ft/. The JavaScript looks like this:

```
$('.select').live('click', function(event) {
    $(event.target)
        .css('background-color', 'green')        
        .prevAll('.select')
        .css('background-color', 'green');
});
```